# Calling the Convert method from Converter just once for each item in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, image, converters, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl control. In its items I show a lot of things: two images in each of the items, some textblocks, etc.

One of the images that are shown in each of the items is the same for all of the items. It's in the Resources.resx file in my project and here's how I load it:

```
<Image Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static properties:Resources.myImageName}" Converter="{StaticResource BitmapToImageConverter}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The Convert method of my BitmapToImageConverter converter class looks like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)value).Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); 

            stream.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage resultImage = new BitmapImage();
            resultImage.BeginInit();                
            resultImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            resultImage.StreamSource = stream;
            resultImage.EndInit();
            resultImage.Freeze();
            return resultImage;
        }
    }
```

Now, the binding takes a lot of time and I want to shorten it somehow. The Convert method gets called once for every item in my itemscontrol, but with the same image (the same parameters). How can I call it just once for all of the items?

The Converter extends the IValueConverter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I havent misunderstood your question Try this

```
public class ImageConverter : ValueConverter
{
    static BitmapImage resultImage = null;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (resultImage != null)
            return resultImage;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)value).Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            stream.Position = 0;
            resultImage = new BitmapImage();
            resultImage.BeginInit();
            resultImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            resultImage.StreamSource = stream;
            resultImage.EndInit();
            resultImage.Freeze();
            return resultImage;
        }
    }
```

Create a static variable and assign it the value first time and return it for next times